# Laravel. Помогите передать в шаблон информацию из базы данных один ко многим

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Существуют много таблиц. Одна характеризует слайдеры, другие содержат информацию внутри слайдеров.
 Главная таблица
[image: Так выглядит таблица главная таблица]
Пример дочерней таблицы, которых много. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача: передать все значения из таблиц в один шаблон. То есть при выборе нужного слайдера из возможных нам выдавало соответствующую информацию.[image: Страница слайдеров]

Что сделано?

1. Таблицы связаны методом один ко многим.
   Главная таблица
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   Дочерние таблицы имеют такую связь
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Создана переменная, которая должна работать с шаблоном в контроллере [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Переменная выведена в шаблон.[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе получаю ошибку Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: W:\domains\jinol\resources\views\admin\adminEditText.blade.php).

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Если еще не нашли ошибку, то ошибка у вас здесь:

```
$info->slider_id->id
```

Потому что вы пытаетесь получить свойство 'id' у переменной не объектного типа (non-object). `$info->slider_id` у вас явно целочисленного типа.

Попытайтесь сделать так:

```
$info->adminSlider->id
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но, к несчастью, это не помогло. Ошибка та же.